# How to share via TCP serial port CAT

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, serial-port

I want to connect my amateur radio transceiver to a linux (Ubuntu) computer with USB cable (serial port (in windows should be COM3 or 
COM4) like /dev/??? ) and share it locally with TCP, Is it possible?

How?

I guess that is possible because I have in my ipad and mac a program that asks host (i guess that would be 192.168.1.104 (the ip of my "server") and port...

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the program you are after is called **ser2net**. It bridges serial streams to TCP ports of your choice. In Ubuntu / Debian do the following:

```
# apt-get install ser2net
```

then edit /etc/ser2net.conf and set up a line such as this:

```
2000:telnet:600:/dev/ttyUSB0:115200 8DATABITS NONE 1STOPBIT banner
```

and finally restart the service

```
# systemctl restart ser2net
```

The config file / man page are well documented but to clarify this will run a TCP service on port 2000, type telnet, 10 minute timeout, connected to /dev/ttyUSB0 with the relevant serial settings. I'm not sure what type of client software you're connecting to your transciever with so you may have to change the connection type from 'telnet' to 'raw' and play with the options, remove the banner etc.

HTH!